# Is it possible to add a new field in a numpy.genfromtxt output?

Tags: python, numpy, genfromtxt

I loaded a csv file and used the header to specify the names of each column.

```
# Load the Data
data = np.genfromtxt('dat_h.csv',
                     delimiter=',',
                     names=True)
```

This is great, because I can access the columns by their name. For example...

```
DATES = data['Dates']
Temperature = data['Temp']
```

Say I have a vector of pressure observations that matches these measurements. Can I append the data structure with a new field that includes my pressure variable?

I want to do something like this ...

```
data.append('Pressure',pressure_vector)
# and then be able to access that field like I do the other fields
data['Pressure']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288736/adding-a-field-to-a-structured-numpy-array-2). Here are the [docs](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/pydoc/numpy.lib.recfunctions.html) for recfunctions.

Mainly I think what you need is this:

```
from numpy.lib.recfunctions import append_fields

append_fields(data, 'Pressure', pressure_vector, np.double)
```