# Adding a field to a structured numpy array (4)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

This has been addressed before ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413947/adding-a-field-to-a-structured-numpy-array-3), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288736/adding-a-field-to-a-structured-numpy-array-2) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201817/adding-a-field-to-a-structured-numpy-array)). I want to add a new field to a structure array returned by numpy `genfromtxt` (also asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40182466/is-it-possible-to-add-a-new-field-in-a-numpy-genfromtxt-output)).

My new problem is that the csv file I'm reading has only a header line and a single data row:

`output-Summary.csv`:

```
Wedge, DWD, Yield (wedge), Efficiency
1, 16.097825, 44283299.473156, 2750887.118836
```

I'm reading it via `genfromtxt` and calculate a new value `'tl'`:

```python
test_out = np.genfromtxt('output-Summary.csv', delimiter=',', names=True)
tl = 300 / test_out['DWD']
```

`test_out` looks like this:

```python
array((1., 16.097825, 44283299.473156, 2750887.118836),
      dtype=[('Wedge', '<f8'), ('DWD', '<f8'), ('Yield_wedge', '<f8'), ('Efficiency', '<f8')])
```

Using `recfunctions.append_fields` (as suggested in the examples 1-3 above) fails over the use of `len()` for the size 1 array:

```python
from numpy.lib import recfunctions as rfn
rfn.append_fields(test_out,'tl',tl)

TypeError: len() of unsized object
```

Searching for alternatives (one of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413947/adding-a-field-to-a-structured-numpy-array-3)) I find that `mlab.rec_append_fields` works well (but is deprecated):

```python
mlab.rec_append_fields(test_out,'tl',tl)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:1: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The rec_append_fields function was deprecated in version 2.2.
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.
```

```python
rec.array((1., 16.097825, 44283299.473156, 2750887.118836, 18.63605798),
          dtype=[('Wedge', '<f8'), ('DWD', '<f8'), ('Yield_wedge', '<f8'), ('Efficiency', '<f8'), ('tl', '<f8')])
```

I can also copy the array over to a new structured array "by hand" as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25427197/numpy-add-column-to-existing-structured-array). This works:

```python
test_out_new = np.zeros(test_out.shape, dtype=new_dt)
for name in test_out.dtype.names:
    test_out_new[name]=test_out[name]
test_out_new['tl']=tl
```

So in summary - is there a way to get `recfunctions.append_fields` to work with the `genfromtxt` output from my single row csv file?
I would really rather use a standard way to handle this rather than a home brew..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reshape the array (and new field) to size (1,).  With just one line, the `genfromtxt` is loading the data as a 0d array, shape ().  The `rfn` code isn't heavily used, and isn't a robust as it should be.  In other words, the 'standard way' is still bit buggy.

For example:

```
In [201]: arr=np.array((1,2,3), dtype='i,i,i')
In [202]: arr.reshape(1)
Out[202]: array([(1, 2, 3)], dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4')])

In [203]: rfn.append_fields(arr.reshape(1), 't1',[1], usemask=False)
Out[203]: 
array([(1, 2, 3, 1)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4'), ('t1', '<i8')])
```

Nothing wrong with the home_brew.  Most of the `rfn` functions use that mechanism - define a new dtype, create a recipient array with that dtype, and copy the fields over, name by name.