# How to hstack arrays of numpy records?

Tags: python, numpy, recarray

<sub>[An earlier version of this post had the inaccurate title "How to add one column to an array of numpy records?"  The question asked *in that earlier title* has already been partially [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201817), but this answer is not quite what the *body* of that earlier version of this post was asking for.  I've reworded the title, and edited the post substantially, to make the distinction clearer.  I also explain why I the answer mentioned earlier falls short of what I'm looking for.]</sub>

---

Suppose I have two `numpy` arrays `x` and `y`, each consisting of *r* "record" (aka "structured") arrays.  Let the shape of `x` be (*r*, *c<sub>x</sub>*) and the shape of `y` be (*r*, *c<sub>y</sub>*).  Let's also assume that there's no overlap between `x.dtype.names` and `y.dtype.names`.

For example, for *r* = 2, *c<sub>x</sub>* = 2, and *c<sub>y</sub>* = 1:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array(zip((1, 2), (3., 4.)), dtype=[('i', 'i4'), ('f', 'f4')])
y = np.array(zip(('a', 'b')), dtype=[('s', 'a10')])
```

I would like to "horizontally" concatenate `x` and `y` to produce a *new* array of records `z`, having shape (*r*, *c<sub>x</sub>* + *c<sub>y</sub>*).  This operation should not modify `x` or `y` at all.

In general, `z = np.hstack((x, y))` won't do, because the `dtype`'s in `x` and `y` won't necessarily match.  E.g., continuing the example above:

```
z = np.hstack((x, y))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-def477e6c8bf> in <module>()
----> 1 z = np.hstack((x, y))
TypeError: invalid type promotion
```

Now, there is a function, `numpy.lib.recfunctions.append_fields`, that *looks* like it may do something close to what I'm looking for, but I have not been able to get anything out of it:  everything I have tried with it either fails with an error, or produces something other than what I'm trying to get.

Can someone please show me *explicitly* the code (using `n.l.r.append_fields` or otherwise<sup>1</sup>) that would generate, from the `x` and `y` defined in the example above, a *new* array of records, `z`, equivalent to the horizontal concatenation of `x` and `y`, and do so without modifying either `x` or `y`?

I assume that this will require only one or two lines of code.  Of course, I am looking for code that does not require building `z`, record by record, by iterating over `x` and `y`.  Also, the code may assume that `x` and `y` have the same number of records, and that there is no overlap between `x.dtype.names` and `y.dtype.names`.  Other than this, the code I'm looking for should know nothing about `x` and `y`.  Ideally, it should be agnostic also about the number of arrays to join.  IOW, leaving out error checking, the code I'm looking for could be the body of a function `hstack_rec` so that the new array `z` would be the result `hstack_rec((x, y))`.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>...although I have to admit that, after my so-far perfect record of failure with `numpy.lib.recfunctions.append_fields`, I've become a bit curious about how this function could be used ***at all***, irrespective of its relevance to this post's question.</sub>

Comment: `d = np.array([3.2], dtype=np.double)
z = rf.append_fields(x, 'field4', data=[d], dtypes=[np.double], usemask=False)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I never use recarrays, and so someone else is going to come up with something slicker, but maybe `merge_arrays` would work?

```
>>> import numpy.lib.recfunctions as nlr
>>> x = np.array(zip((1, 2), (3., 4.)), dtype=[('i', 'i4'), ('f', 'f4')])
>>> y = np.array(zip(('a', 'b')), dtype=[('s', 'a10')])
>>> x
array([(1, 3.0), (2, 4.0)], 
      dtype=[('i', '<i4'), ('f', '<f4')])
>>> y
array([('a',), ('b',)], 
      dtype=[('s', '|S10')])
>>> z = nlr.merge_arrays([x, y], flatten=True)
>>> z
array([(1, 3.0, 'a'), (2, 4.0, 'b')], 
      dtype=[('i', '<i4'), ('f', '<f4'), ('s', '|S10')])
```

Comment: It's worth noting that despite `recfunctions` being named as such, `merge_arrays` also works on structured arrays, not just record arrays! A pleasant surprise.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very late answer, but maybe it will be helpful to someone else. I used this solution after asking the same question with most of the same criteria.

It doesn't generate a new numpy array, but by using `zip` and `itertools.chain` it is much faster. In my case, I needed to access every value of every row in sequential order. Here is benchmark which simulates this use-case:

```
import numpy
from numpy.lib.recfunctions import merge_arrays
from itertools import chain

a = numpy.empty(3, [("col1", int), ("col2", float)])
b = numpy.empty(3, [("col3", int), ("col4", "U1")])
```

Results:

```
%timeit [i for i in (row for row in merge_arrays([a,b], flatten=True))]
52.9 µs ± 2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit [i for i in (row for row in (chain(i,k) for i,k in zip(a,b)))]
3.47 µs ± 52 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```