# Adding a field to a structured numpy array (3)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

This has been asked and answered several times ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201817/adding-a-field-to-a-structured-numpy-array) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288736/adding-a-field-to-a-structured-numpy-array-2/), for instance). Apparently the function has been moved in numpy 1.6.1. There is no more `numpy.lib.recfunctions`. While I can implement my own as specified in previous posts, I would **really** rather not!

Can someone tell me the path to this function? Have `recfunctions` as a whole been moved or merged into another library?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [git history](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/commits/6c729b4423857850e6553cf6c2d0fc8b026036dd/numpy/lib/recfunctions.py), `numpy.lib.recfunctions` hasn't gone anywhere.

I'd check your installation of numpy, and perhaps upgrade it to a newer version.

Comment: okay. Thanks for that. I've found the library and the function, so I'm thinking I have something funky w/my configuration. Will report back.

Comment: ran into this issue using linux/conda on a new system. Had to add a `import numpy.lib.recfunctions` call at the top.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me... but I'm not clear why. Maybe someone can explain:

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.__version__
'1.6.1'
>>> numpy.lib
<module 'numpy.lib' from 'C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.pyc'>
>>> numpy.lib.recfunctions    #### <- why does this not work?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'recfunctions'
>>> import numpy.lib.recfunctions
>>> dir(numpy.lib.recfunctions)
['MaskedArray', 'MaskedRecords', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '_check_fill_value', '_fix_defaults', '_fix_output','_is_string_like', '_izip_fields', '_izip_fields_flat', 'append_fields', 'drop_fields', 'find_duplicates', 'flatten_descr', 'get_fieldstructure', 'get_names', 'get_names_flat', 'itertools', 'izip_records', 'join_by', 'ma', 'merge_arrays', 'ndarray', 'np', 'rec_append_fields', 'rec_drop_fields', 'rec_join', 'recarray', 'recursive_fill_fields', 'rename_fields', 'stack_arrays', 'sys', 'zip_descr']
>>>
```

Comment: That's interesting. Explicitly using `import numpy.lib.recfunctions` works for me as well. At least this is a workaround. Still would like to know why I can't get to `recfunctions` with the normal `import numpy; numpy.lib.recfunctions` approach.

Comment: I still have the same issue with numpy 1.19.2. Super weird.

Answer (score 0):

I found that to append array to a record array,  use mlab recfunctions is OK but numpy recfunctions is NOT OK.

```
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
mlab.rec_append_fields(recarray, names, data)
```

Comment: is there any reason for your assessment?