# Insert field into structured array at a specific column index

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I'm currently using `np.loadtxt` to load some mixed data into a structured numpy array. I do some calculations on a few of the columns to output later. For compatibility reasons I need to maintain a specific output format so I'd like to insert those columns at specific points and use `np.savetxt` to export the array in one shot.

A simple setup:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.zeros((2,),dtype=('i4,f4,a10'))
x[:] = [(1,2.,'Hello'),(2,3.,'World')]

newcol = ['abc','def']
```

For this example I'd like to make `newcol` the 2nd column. I'm very new to Python (coming from MATLAB). From my searching all I've been able to find so far are ways to [append `newcol` to the end of `x`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201817/adding-a-field-to-a-structured-numpy-array) to make it the last column, or `x` to `newcol` to make it the first column. I also turned up `np.insert` but it doesn't seem to work on a structured array because it's technically a 1D array (from my understanding).

What's the most efficient way to accomplish this?

EDIT1:

I investigated `np.savetxt` a little further and it seems like it can't be used with a structured array, so I'm assuming I would need to loop through and write each row with `f.write`. I could specify each column explicitly (by field name) with that approach and not have to worry about the order in my structured array, but that doesn't seem like a very generic solution.

For the above example my desired output would be:

```
1, abc, 2.0, Hello
2, def, 3.0, World
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'I'd like to make newcol the 2nd column'? `x` does not have columns, it is a 1d array right? Can you show us the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a way to add a field to the array, at the position you require:

```
from numpy import zeros, empty


def insert_dtype(x, position, new_dtype, new_column):
    if x.dtype.fields is None:
        raise ValueError, "`x' must be a structured numpy array"
    new_desc = x.dtype.descr
    new_desc.insert(position, new_dtype)
    y = empty(x.shape, dtype=new_desc)
    for name in x.dtype.names:
        y[name] = x[name]
    y[new_dtype[0]] = new_column
    return y


x = zeros((2,), dtype='i4,f4,a10')
x[:] = [(1, 2., 'Hello'), (2, 3., 'World')]

new_dt = ('my_alphabet', '|S3')
new_col = ['abc', 'def']

x = insert_dtype(x, 1, new_dt, new_col)
```

Now `x` looks like

```
array([(1, 'abc', 2.0, 'Hello'), (2, 'def', 3.0, 'World')], 
  dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('my_alphabet', 'S3'), ('f1', '<f4'), ('f2', 'S10')])
```

The solution is adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201817/adding-a-field-to-a-structured-numpy-array).

To print the recarray to file, you could use something like:

```
from matplotlib.mlab import rec2csv
rec2csv(x,'foo.txt')
```